# How to change default font size in menus after Wine?

Tags: wine, fonts, microsoft-word

I am using `Wine 1.4.1` to run `MS Word 2010` in Ubuntu 12.10. Yet, the font size and menus in `Word` are just **too small**. Have a look:

[image]

Is there a way for me to change the Word font size and menu sizes? I.e. the fonts of the system?

I tried following [these instructions](http://www.ehow.com/how_6931859_adjust-fonts-wine-ubuntu.html) (to no avail), and also [gave a look into these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134542/fonts-look-bad-in-microsoft-office-using-wine) (though the problem is very different).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a know FIXED bug in wine for the menu's being too big, maybe this will help.

[Word 2010 UI uses wrong font size](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30869)

Answer (score 6):

Start `winecfg`, select the 'Graphics' tab and increase the dpi.

Comment: Awesome! This totally worked! I'm using PlayOnLinux, which uses Wine in the background, and this worked perfectly for my program (LTSpice). Here's my answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1097341/327339

Answer (score 1):

If using PlayOnLinux, which uses Wine in the background:

The following worked perfectly for my program (LTSpice).

Open PlayOnLinux --> click "Configure" button --> Wine tab --> Configure Wine --> (this opens up the "Wine configuration" window for this specific app in PlayOnLinux, which is the same kind of window you see when you run `winecfg` from the terminal) --> Graphics tab --> Drag the Screen Resolution slider up from 96 dpi to perhaps 120 dpi.

Fixed!

## Examples

### Before (96 dpi):

Wine configuration window where I set this:
[image]

Running LTSpice in PlayOnLinux (which uses Wine)--showing the Control Panel in LTSpice (notice the small font in the center window, and the small File, Edit, Hierarchy, etc. dropdown names at the top, as compared to the 144 dpi version farther below):
[image]

### After (144 dpi, for example):

Wine configuration window where I set this:
[image]

Running LTSpice in PlayOnLinux (which uses Wine)--showing the Control Panel in LTSpice. Notice how much bigger the center window and File, Edit, Hierarchy, etc. dropdown names at the top are here as compared to the previous screenshot in the 96 dpi example above):
[image]