# How do I change font size of Wine program (not the menu buttons)?

Tags: wine, fonts, games

I know I can change font size of the menu buttons in `winecfg` (e.g. [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962415/401385)), but that does not change the font size of text in the game (i.e. the name of the character, "Zanma Rouga", and the conversation text) May I ask is there a way I can change the font size (or maybe even better, all font settings) of the text inside the game?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> May I ask is there a way I can change the font size (or maybe even better, all font settings) of the text inside the game?

If there is a .tff inside the folder you can replace it by a font file you do like. So find for instance an Arial.tff, copy it over the .tff and the game will start to use Arial and all the characteristics of that font.

It will require some experimenting: if the text is still too large and you can not find a suitable font you will need to find the string used for that specific text and replace the size by a smaller size.

- Fontforge (`sudo apt install fontforge`) is a tool that can help with that (it also has a its own scripting language to automate altering font files).

If there is no .tff the text is likely hard coded into the game (and likely making it impossible).

I would suggest to ask this on [WineHQ](https://forum.winehq.org/viewforum.php?f=2) though as the people there are likely to answer it *specifically* for Big Bang.